# Como rrecorrer un arreglo bidimencional en c#

Tags: c#, integer

```
int[,]miarreglo={{2,1,11,45},{44,3,33,10}};
```

Si tengo un arreglo como este como puedo iterar sus filas y columnas con ciclos for

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo que lo podes hacer así:

GetLength toma un número entero que especifica la dimensión de la matriz que está consultando y devuelve su longitud. La propiedad de Length devuelve la cantidad total de elementos en una matriz:

```
int[,,] a = new int[10,11,12];
Console.WriteLine(a.Length);           // 1320
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(0));     // 10
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(1));     // 11
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(2));     // 12
```

Entonces

```
for (int i = 0; i < miarreglo.GetLength(0); i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < miarreglo.GetLength(1); k++){
        Console.Write(miarreglo[i, k] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Abunda más en tu explicación, explica para que se usa el método getlength

Comment: hola @Japv no tengo fresco en memoria como responder, creo que el OP (creo que así se dice) pide como hacerlo, yo le pase un ejemplo. No esta dentro de mis habilidades explicar correctamente, pero usando google, se pude saber por que.

Comment: GetLength toma un número entero que especifica la dimensión de la matriz que está consultando y devuelve su longitud. La propiedad de Length  devuelve la cantidad total de elementos en una matriz:                              
`int[,,] a = new int[10,11,12];                                    Console.WriteLine(a.Length);           // 1320
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(0));     // 10
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(1));     // 11
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(2));     // 12`                                                     
Fuente: [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044602/12071902)

Comment: Santiago no me lo tienes que decir a mí sino al op, edita tu pregunta y da esa explicación ahí

Comment: Ahí la modifique. @Japv pido disculpa si no me se explicar bien, solo aporte, con un ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: hola muy amable  por tu respuesta efectivamente lo probe y me funciono